# Environment map has an edge

Tags: three.js

I have a bunch of boxes with a CubeTexture set to the EnvMap of their sides, when I move the boxes I notice there happens to be a seam when I move them to the very far left and right of the screen.

[Video here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDYWe.jpg)

I tried changing the texture with new images but the seam stays there. I also tried offsetting the texture or changing the repeating but to no avail.

The only thing that works is moving the camera forward or back in the Z axis.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the example envmap images that come with three.js? To me, it looks like an issue with your envmap textures.

Comment: @TheJim01 I just tried it with the Bridge2 textures and it doesn't seem to have the problem, thanks for the help I'll look more into the texture.